# How to pass two parameters to System.Func

Tags: parameters, expression, func

I have a function like this

```
public BuildColumn<TModel> TEST<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
    string DisplayName, 
    object HTMLAttributes,
    Expression<Func<TModel, string, TProperty>> SpecialHTMLAttributes, 
    bool Show) {}
```

If you look at the 4th argument, it's an `Expression<Func<TModel,string,TProperty>>`. What I am trying to do here is pass a lambda expression and a string value, maybe "abc" . But I could not figure out how to pass them in this argument or how to use it.
Does anyone knows how to pass 2 parameters to a `System.Func<>`, or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you'd like to do or how you want to use this?  It's a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is the parameter type you want:

```
Func<TModel, string, TProperty>
```

Or the expression form:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, string, TProperty>>
```

That would allow you to to pass something like this as the argument:

```
(model, str) => model.SomeCode(str)
```